# Reduce size importing moment.js

Tags: vuejs2, momentjs, webpack-4

I followed the suggestions reported [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-reduce-your-vue-js-bundle-size-with-webpack-3145bf5019b7) to reduce my Vue.JS SAP bundle size, and in details, importing moment as:

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment'
```

or even better with an alias set within "configureWebpack" section of "vue.config.js", but in doing so I receive the following error when running `npm run build` or `npm run serve`:

```
Can't resolve './locale' in '/path_folder_project/node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale'
```

I was not able to resolve it, any suggestion?
The installed moment.js module is @2.29.1.